# Obstacles remain in costmap despite observation_persistence being set

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question is mostly a duplicate of [this one](https://answers.ros.org/question/35854/meaning-of-costmap_2d-observation_persistence-parameter/) but since it was closed without answer long ago, I open a new one.

I expected that when observations are removed after the given time, the corresponding obstacle should disappear from the costmap. However, this does not happen, the obstacles stay there forever.

Is this a bug and the observation_persistence parameter is not working as intended? Or is it expected behaviour? In this case, what is the purpose of this parameter?

In any case: Is there a way how I can achieve my desired behaviour (i.e. obstacles disappear after some time from the costmap when they are no longer supported by current observations)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280067/obstacles-remain-in-costmap-despite-observation_persistence-being-set/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One [not well maintained] solution: https://github.com/DLu/decaying_obstacle_layer

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2018-01-23**:
oh man this is this awesome. Thanks David!!!! Lu!

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2018-01-24**:
@Felix Widmaier  did you ever get this work for you? Mine still leaves fantom obstacles. :(

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-01-25**:
@psammut: Unfortunately, I did not yet have the time to give it a try (currently I simply clear the whole costmap from time to time).

**Comment by [isuru_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/50731/isuru_m/) on 2021-10-01**:
@David Lu is this package available for ROS kinetic ?